# Button click problem

Tags: android, button, click, android-edittext

I'm a beginner in application development. My problem is, that when I run my app and I click on the Calculate button, the program stops. The code:

```
public class screen1 extends Activity {
    private EditText name; 
    private CheckBox box1;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private TextView text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6;
    private Button calcbutton, closebutton;
    String strength;  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Spinner hubSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.military_ranks , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        hubSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);      
        strength = name.getText().toString();  

        box1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        text3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        text4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        text5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        text6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView14);

        final Button calcbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        calcbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int str = Integer.valueOf(strength);
                int rank = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;
                double sebzes;
                if(box1.isChecked()){
                    sebzes = (((rank-1)/20+0.3)*((str/10)+40))*1*(1+1/100);
                    text1.setText(Double.toString(sebzes));
                }
                else{
                    sebzes = (((rank-1)/20+0.3)*((str/10)+40))*1;
                    text1.setText(Double.toString(sebzes));
                }
            }
        });

        final Button closebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        closebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the `edittext` component you should be able to write numbers only. I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: You have to post your log. Then we can see where to code fails. I assume that this is a problem:  int str = Integer.valueOf(strength);

Comment: What is up with the editing all of a sudden? That popup is horrible.

Comment: I'm talking about StackOverflow, not your code sample (which is not horrible at all). :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem are these two lines:

```
 int str = Integer.valueOf(strength);
 int rank = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;
```

The first won't fail if you use only numbers in your EditText but it would be better to ensure that or at least catch the exception that is thrown when you try to convert a character to a numberical value. Additionally you could also use `Integer.valueOf(strength).intValue();` even so it is normally not really necessary.

The real problem is the second line. You declared the variable `spinner` but you never instantiate it. That's why you will get a NullPointerException there.

On an unrelated note: You also should start your class name with a capital letter to follow the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You're not instantiating `spinner` anywhere, but you're referencing it in the second line of your button click method.  Probably a null reference problem.